# printing javascript object in HTML

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am trying to print a `javascript` object whose content i don't know in `HTML`

```
$(".side div .data").replaceWith('<p class="data">' + $.each(d, function (key, value) {
    return key;
}) + '</p>');
```

I want to loop through the object and print their `key-value` pairs

Comment: Can you detail a little be more what you want by giving example please? And the structure of your `d` variable

Comment: `JSON.stringify(d)`?

Answer (score 0):

if the Object does not contain looping references you can use

```
JSON.stringify(object)
```

Otherwise you can try for in loop

```
for(var i in obj) {
    console.log(i + " : " + obj[i]);
}
```

Comment: Two completely different things.

Comment: :) I won't defend that, these are different. But may be can get the job done.

Answer (score 0):

> want to loop through the object and print their key-value pairs

Try using `$.map()` , `Array.prototype.join()`

```js
var d = {a:1, b:2, c:3};

$(".side div .data").replaceWith('<p class="data">' 
  + $.map(d, function (value, key) {
    return key + ":" + value;
  }).join(" ") 
+ '</p>');
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="side">
  <div>
  <span class="data"></span>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

if you don't want date to be print in any specific formate then silmply use `$(".data").append(JSON.stringify(d));` otherwise try the following

```js
var d = {
  a: 1,
  b: 2,
  c: 3
};
$.each(d, function(i, item) {
  $(".data").append(i + ' -> ' + item + '<br> ');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="side">
  <div>
    <span class="data"></span>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

From your mark up in the code you provided, it looks like you are trying to do...

```
$(".side div .data").html(JSON.stringify(d))
```

or even just.... as the stuff you are returning may already be in format html

```
$(".side div .data").html(d)
```